# Channel Form is not inserting <p> tags like Channel Entries does; all <p> tags mysteriously gone from entries

Tags: channel-form, tags, rte, formatting

When we enter properly formatted HTML into the RTE via the CP, the `<p>` tags are present. But when we use the `{exp:channel:form ...}` we lose all the `<p>` tags but retain all other tags. We're using `Textarea (Rich Text)` fields because we need the RTE on our custom dashboard.

I tested the `{exp:channel:entries ...}` and the `<p>` tags were properly retained.

So what could be causing this? How can we fix it? We need the channel form to output the proper tags because we have a live preview of what's in the populated `textarea` elements.

---

Update:

When using `{field:my_channel_field}` the `<p>` tags are retained, but the RTE isn't created. It's just a `textarea` with html/text.

---

Update 2:

I did some digging and found that in the SQL tables there are no `<p>` tags, meaning that they're inserted when the data is called.

For instance this is what's actually in the Database

```
<h3>Lorem nascetur </h3> Porttitor. Integer nunc. Hac ultricies velit magnis. Nunc est, tortor proin?
```

And this what is output when using `{exp:channel:entries ...}`:

```
<h3>Lorem nascetur </h3>

<p> Porttitor. Integer nunc. Hac ultricies velit magnis. Nunc est, tortor proin?</p>
```

So at some point the `<p>` tags are being injected into the document, and I want to know how can I force this so they are in the RTE when the user goes to edit them within an `{exp:channel:form ...}` loop?

---

Update 3:

I found these in `/system/expressionengine/modules/rte/libraries/Rte_lib.php` on lines 445 to 446

```
// Strip paragraph tags
$data = preg_replace("#<(/)?pre[^>]*?>#i", "<$1pre>", $data);
$data = preg_replace("#<p>|<p(?!re)[^>]*?".">|</p>#i", "",  preg_replace("#<\/p><p(?!re)[^>]*?".">#i", "\n", $data));
```

and

```
if (stristr($str, '<p') !== FALSE)
{
    $str = preg_replace("#<(/)?pre[^>]*?>#i", "<$1pre>", $str);
    $str = preg_replace("#<p>|<p(?!re)[^>]*?".">|</p>#i", "",  preg_replace("#<\/p><p(?!re)[^>]*?".">#i", "\n", $str));
}
```

in `/system/expressionengine/libraries/EE_Typography.php`.

Commenting them out didn't seem to solve the problem

---

Update 4:

I tested my theory more completely by simply doing a `{exp:channel:entries ...}` and `{exp:channel:form ..}` on a blank template with nothing other than a field.

When output, the `channel:form` actually outputs HTML tags (`<h3>` from update 2 above) that never get rendered, and the `channel:entries` outputs the correct HTML and does get rendered. See picture:

[image: Example of channel:form output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much consternation I tried commenting out the `Strip paragraph tags` section of the `save_field()` function from above again, but tested it more thoroughly and it works. It keeps the tags on submission/repopulation through `channel:form`. This might cause bugs down the line, but it'll do for now.

`/system/expressionengine/modules/rte/libraries/Rte_lib.php`

lines 445 to 447.

```
// Strip paragraph tags
/*
$data = preg_replace("#<(/)?pre[^>]*?>#i", "<$1pre>", $data);
$data = preg_replace("#<p>|<p(?!re)[^>]*?".">|</p>#i", "",  preg_replace("#<\/p><p(?!re)[^>]*?".">#i", "\n", $data));
*/
```